# Intent for GPS-location in NFC tag

Tags: android, gps, nfc

I am working on an app that reads NFC-tags.
A basic NFC tag already works, and reads well. However, if I use a NFC tag that contains GPS information in form of Latitude and Longitude, my app does not seem to get noticed.
I assume that this is because my

```
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
```

is not fit to activte my MainActivity with a GPS-tag.
So here my question, which I was uanble to find anywhere:
What to (additionally) specify, in order for the NFC-Tag with gps data to kick my app?
The Pop-up for other apps works, so TagWriter or Google Maps get along with this GPS-NFC-Tag.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you store the lat/lon data on your tag? Your intent filter goes for the mime type text/plain. Is that the way how you store the GPS data?

Comment: I do store them with an app called TagWriter. You can pick "GPS" there directly.

Comment: Tagwriter stores the lat/lon data as a URI record in the form: geo:lat,lon (e.g. geo:40.46852,-98.59231). Your intent filter needs to specify such a URI. For example:  <data android:scheme="geo" android:host="*" />